# Simple mvc routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to submit a form from partial view, but keep getting 404.
Here's the form:

```
@model PMP.WebUI.Models.ViewModel.VMTakeQuiz

@using (Html.BeginForm("Quiz", "QuizController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "take-quiz-form" }))
{   
..
<input type="submit" name="LaunchQuiz" value="Launch Quiz!" class="submit-button" />  
..  
}
```

Here's the map route assignment (it's the second assignment after the usual ignore axd's one):

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Quiz",
           "Quiz/Quiz",
           new { controller = "Quiz", action = "Quiz" }
);
```

And here's the controller and its action:

```
public class QuizController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Quiz(VMTakeQuiz quiz)
        {
            return null;
        }  
}
```

What I'm getting is 404 on: `Requested URL: /QuizController/Quiz`

What should I change to route the form submit to the given action?

Comment: Why do you have a custom route, and not let the default routing handle it?  Removing your custom route would work just fine from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass just controller name without 'controller' postfix like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Quiz", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "take-quiz-form" }))
{   
..
```

Requested URL should be: /Quiz/Quiz

Answer (score 1):

For controller you don't need to append `controller suffix` with their names

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Quiz", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "take-quiz-form" }))
```

Also try to have different name for your views and controllers. :)